# Capture stdout for a remote process' child process

Tags: c++, winapi, pipe, win32-process

Currently working on a situation where I need to capture the stdout/stderr for a child process of an external process. For this situation would I need a named pipe?

I have currently tried the following:

```
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;
HANDLE hStdOutRd = NULL;
HANDLE hStdOutWr = NULL;
HANDLE hDupStdOutWr = NULL;

saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); 
saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL; 

CreatePipe(&hStdOutRd, &hStdOutWr, &saAttr, 0) ) 
SetHandleInformation(hStdOutRd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) )

HANDLE hExProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, false, EXTERNAL_PROC);
DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), 
                hStdOutWr, 
                hExProc,
                &hDupStdOutWr, 
                0,
                TRUE,
                DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);

// Child process for EXTERNAL_PROC executes and should inherit the duplicated handle
// Read from hStdOutRd
```

When reading from the pipe, it either hangs or doesn't return anything. I'm assuming this is the case that it is an anonymous pipe and only works for parent-child processes and not external processes. I would prefer to not use a Named Pipe, would it be possible to DuplicateHandle() the pipes back from the remote process to my process and then access the data? If so, what would that look like?

Comment: This is operating system specific. Without mention of an OS, your question is unclear. Perhaps you should consider frameworks like [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) or [Qt](http://qt.io/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch the code in question is using Win32 API functions so clearly it is meant to run on Windows only.

Comment: Indeed, but you had to edit the tags.

Comment: named pipes the same as un-nmamed or so called anonymous pipe. at you need use asynchronous io for never hung. and `CreatePipe` is bad for this target. much more better use `CreateNamedPipe +CreateFile`. `DuplicateHandle` - and how you notify child of duplicated value ?

Comment: @RbMm: That's like saying: An unnamed pipe is the same as a named pipe, just with less name. Not exactly helpful. Even when represented by the same kernel structure, the available services through the API *are* different, as [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365137.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable - yes, this is the absolute the same - some file object on `\Device\NamedPipe` - different only in concrete name. and services - *not different* - this is how i say absolute the same. exist different api call for create named and un-named (or random named before win7) pipe. and all. all another the same

Comment: @RbMm: So everything is exactly the same, except for the differences, eh? That, too, is hardly helpful in making a point. And the point you are trying to make is not relevant anyway.

Comment: @IInspectable -everything is exactly the same, except for concrete name. are exist difference between  `\Device\NamedPipe\X` and `\Device\NamedPipe\Y` where `X` and `Y` any characters set (can be and empty) ? name different but the same by type file object. and this is useful for understanding. i be say - anonymous pipe pair - 2 named pipe created via `CreatePipe` with some default properties

Comment: and before win7 - `CreatePipe` simply create 2 random named named pipes. begin from win7 - possible create exactly unnamed pair. say `CreatePipe` always create synchronous pipes. but we can create it yourself, direct as asynchronous. can just create one inheritable and one - no. can create both duplex. really `CreatePipe` very restricted api.

Comment: and this is very relevant - need clear understand - not exist 2 different pipe types(named vs un-named or random named) - exist simply pipes and all. simply exist single documented api call `CreatePipe` which create unnamed pipe pair - with simply interface but restricted customization (set pipe properties). all. operations is the same. and possible create un-named pair direct (via native calls only) with any wanted properties

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need to use a named pipe, an anonymous pipe will do fine. MSDN provides a full example of capturing output from a child process:

[Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499.aspx)

Comment: named pipe and an anonymous pipe - is absolute the same object. and msdn example from my opinion pretty bad.

Comment: OP is asking about capturing output from a process that he didn't launch (handle obtained via `OpenProcess()`), which I believe is not (easily) doable.

Comment: @zett42 I didn't notice the `OpenProcess()` part. In that case, you can't redirect output for a process that you did not launch yourself.

Comment: what if I launch the process myself with CreateProcess() and STARTUPINFOEX + PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS? Would duplicating the handle to the remote parent I specify and setting bInheritHandle get me access to the child's stdout?

Comment: @NotWarrenBuffet: regardless of which process you assign as the child's parent, when you call `CreateProcess()` directly, you can provide your own `STD(IN|OUT|ERR)` pipes for the new child via the `STARTUPINFO/EX` struct, just like the article I linked to in my answer demonstrates. You don't need to duplicate anything. Enable the `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` flag in the `dwFlags` field, and then assign the read end of a pipe to the `hStdOut` and `hStdError` fields.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I guess I was under the impression that the handle inheritance such as `bInheritHandle` was having the child process inherit the handles to the `STD(IN|OUT|ERR)` pipes from the parent so they can be written to. What you are saying is this is not the case and I can just supply the appropriate pipes to the `hStdOut` and `hStdError` fields and the handles will make it to the new process regardless of child/parent relationship?

Comment: @NotWarrenBuffet yes. You really need to read the documentation more carefully.